# Is it possible to extract data from api response from main domain?

Tags: xss, api, sub-domain

I found an XSS on `subdomain.example.com`, is it possible to use that xss to extract the response of an api request from the main domain `example.com/api/xyz`?

The xss is on `subdomain.example.com` and I'd like to extract the whole response of `www.example.com/api/xyz`. Is it possible to do it via XSS?

If possible, which javascript code could I use?

Comment: document.domain only works with frames, ajax needs CORS, so the answer depends on the CORS headers set by example.com.

Comment: I'm going to go with the StackOverflow-approach here and ask: "What have you tried so far?"